# ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 in react native & iOS development

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, expo

I'm trying to build a simple react native app that highlights texts. Initially I was making in expo and have **ejected** and have tried to integrate the https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text library.

After following Astrocoder's instruction to integrate, I get the following error. What I'm most confused about is that the conflict (RNSelectableTextView.o and Manager.o) seems to be happening from the same library, not different libraries like other examples, which should be building on each other...

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextManager._onHighlightPress' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextManager._menuItems' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNSelectableTextManager' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RNSelectableTextManager' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextManager._onSelection' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextManager._value' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextManager.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNSelectableTextView' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RNSelectableTextView' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextView._backedTextInputView' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_selectionStart' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextView._onHighlightPress' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextView._menuItems' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextView._onSelection' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_beginning' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNSelectableTextView._value' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
duplicate symbol '_CUSTOM_SELECTOR' in:
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSelectableText/libRNSelectableText.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
    /Users/sanghapark/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/trialv1-fheptlkmdwwaaecmpyvoheysshnb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-selectable-text/libreact-native-selectable-text.a(RNSelectableTextView.o)
ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

warning: no rule to process file '/Users/sanghapark/Documents/trial_v2/client/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/sanghapark/Documents/trial_v2/client/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt' of type 'text' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/sanghapark/Documents/trial_v2/client/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.6.99. (in target 'RNSelectableText' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.6.99. (in target 'OpenSSL-Universal' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.6.99. (in target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **
```

Any suggestion as to how to go about this? Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!
Below are my react native info and pod file for reference.

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.3
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7267U CPU @ 3.10GHz
    Memory: 18.89 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.18.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.6, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223
    Xcode: 11.6/11E708 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.8 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: ~16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
    react-native: ^0.62.2 => 0.62.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.33.1'
  versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.1'
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.0'

  pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'

  # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
  # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
  pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
end

# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'trialv1' do
  # Pods for trialv1
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'RNSelectableText', :path => '../node_modules/@astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text/ios/RNSelectableText.podspec'

  use_unimodules!
  use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  add_flipper_pods!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

I've been able to figure it out. Follow the https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios instruction.

1. npm install [library]
2. npx react-native link

Good to go! No need for manually copying and pasting to Pod file.